# What is the GLboolean values denoting true and false?

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am  using Haskell's OpenGL.Raw library and I wish to use the GLboolean values for true and false, but they don't seem to be predefined in the library. How do I define these values myself?

Answer (score 1):

The two functions used for this in the OpenGL library are (in the internal module GLBoolean)

```
marshalGLboolean :: Num a => Bool -> a
marshalGLboolean x = fromIntegral $ case x of
   False -> gl_FALSE
   True -> gl_TRUE

unmarshalGLboolean :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
unmarshalGLboolean = (/= fromIntegral gl_FALSE)
```

`GLBoolean` is an instance of the Num typeclass, but you need to convert the normal `Bool` values at every place you use an OpenGL function. If you don't want to convert it at every place then you can use the following

```
gTrue, gFalse :: Num a => a
gTrue = fromIntegral gl_TRUE
gFalse = fromIntegral gl_FALSE
```

But the disadvantage is that you cannot use the normal boolean operations like `&&` and `||`.
Or you could let the OpenGL library do the wrapping for you, which also brings allong some typesafety and an interface that might be a bit better.